# angularjs ui-router go to state after relogin

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to go to the link I entered or clicked before unauthorized response received and successful login.

The scenario:

1. Enter any link.
2. Receive unauthorized response with http interceptor.
3. Redirect to login page.
4. Successfully logged in.
5. **Redirect to originally entered link.**

What is the best way to implement **the 5 step** with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try catching the `$stateChangeSuccess` event broadcasted by `ui-router` and keeping a list of the last few visited states (and their params). Then after re-login, you'd just look at your list to find out what state was last visited before your login state.

---

Of course, the above is just one example of many possible approaches. To give another example, you could pass currently selected state (and its params) to login state as (hidden) params.

Comment: If I try to extend your idea - I can catch the `$stateChangeError` and save the requested state and it's additional data. And after login I can go to the saved state.

Comment: If you want to redirect even to the state the user previously "wanted to go to but didn't reach", you could try catching the `$stateChangeStart` event instead.